# Ethernet UDP First Received Packet is Delayed. Why?

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireshark, delay

I have a PC exchanging data using gigabit Ethernet with some custom hardware. My problem is that when data physically arrives on the network card (checked with an oscilloscope), the first frame is registered by the OS with a delay of approximately 1ms. All subsequent frames are registered with very little delay.

If I needed to transmit a large chunk of data this would be acceptable since the delay would only be present for the first frame, however, my application requires me to send a single packet and wait for a reply. This 1ms delay on every received packet is significantly reducing my bandwidth.

ARP negotiation is not the issue as i have set the entry as static. I am observing received packet timing using wireshark. Anyone know what could cause a delay to be present in only the first read frame?

Comment: What *exactly* does "registered by the OS" mean? Is your app already running, or is it getting launched by launchd or inetd or some other lazy-launch daemon that's actually listening on the port?

Comment: By registered I mean the time it takes to show in wireshark, i am assuming thats the time at which it reaches the receive buffer. App is already running, i have a UDP listener in an infinite loop (C#). I have also tried commercial terminals such as packet sender.

Comment: Can you define exactly what you mean by "first frame"? First after link up? First from this IP host? First of this UDP flow? First of this large buffer write on the sending side? Is EEE (802.3az) in use on this link? Where exactly did you hook up the o'scope? Was it on GMII or somewhere else? Is the custom hardware the PC's gigabit ethernet NIC itself, or does that refer to the device on the other end of the gigabit ethernet link?

Comment: Some background: I am sending frames to an FPGA with a RGMII phy. When the FPGA receives the frame it immediately re-transmits the same frame, so the delay from reception/transmission is very low. If i send a single frame at any time during uplink the frame is returned back with 1ms delay. If i send continuous frames from the pc, the stream is recieved with a 1ms delay (so the first frame arrives appears in OS buffer 1ms late, but the rest of the frames arrive immediately after).

Comment: Also if I transmit/receive/transmit continuously the 1ms delay is only present on the first  frame in the sequence, however if i stop sending/receiving for more then approximetly 2ms the 1ms delay on the first frame is observed again. By observing the RGMII timing i am fairly sure that the delay of 1ms is from the OS side.